# PHP && giving wrong answer

Tags: php, logic, php-7

I'm converting some VB code to PHP, and in one line there is a logic operator AND.

The PHP and VB are giving me different results, so breaking down each step, it boils down to the logic operator AND, or && as it is in PHP.

In PHP I have:

```
($intAscii && $a)
```

with values of `$intAscii = 87` and `$a = 128`.

The above logic should return 0, but PHP returns 1.

Converting these to binary:

```
    87 = ‭01010111‬
    128 = 10000000‬
```

so it seems obvious this should return 0, so why does PHP insist on returning 1?

Full function here:

```
    Function IsBitSet($intAscii , $intBit) {

        //'change the value of the integer passed by
        //'turning on the bit passed
        $a=(int)(pow(2 ,(int)$intBit));
        $b=($intAscii && $a);
        echo '</br>Manual AND  87 && 128 '.(87 && 128) .'</br>';
        echo 'is bit set $intAscii='.$intAscii .' $a='.$a.' And = '.( $b).'</br>';

        Return(($intAscii && $a) <> 0);

    }
```

and the output:

```
Manual AND 87 && 128 1
is bit set $intAscii=84 $a=128 And = 1
```

Comment: `&&` and `&` are different operators.

Comment: I'm not using &...

Comment: And in your case you __should__ use `&` and not `&&`.

Comment: Why? https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php The PHP AND operator is &&, and that's what I'm trying to acheive - so why is it & and not &&? Take the manual 87 && 128 for example - that doesn't return the correct result using the correct operator.

Comment: Read the manual - "TRUE if both $a and $b are TRUE." Both 87 and 128 are TRUE. And now open this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php and read about `&`.

Comment: Thanks u-mulder. I wasn't aware of the & | and ^ bitwise operators.